# Assign data into class with lists

Tags: c#, list, oop

I have the class below

```
public class G481Vars
{
    public double Disp { get; set; }
    public double IniVel { get; set; }
    public double FinVel { get; set; }
    public double Acc { get; set; }
    public double Time { get; set; }
    public double Force { get; set; }
    public double Mass { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public double Press { get; set; }
    public double Dens { get; set; }
    public double Energy { get; set; }
    public double Area { get; set; }
    public double Vol { get; set; }
}
```

And i have made a list as such:

```
List<G481Vars> G481List = new List<G481Vars>();
```

With an array of input boxes defined as

```
HtmlInputText[] G481Inputs = new HtmlInputText[13]
{
    G481Disp_Txt, G481IniVel_Txt, G481FinVel_Txt, G481Acc_Txt,
    G481Time_Txt, G481Force_Txt, G481Mass_Txt, G481Weight_Txt,
    G481Press_Txt, G481Dens_Txt, G481Energy_Txt, G481Area_Txt,
    G481Vol_Txt
};
```

How would one go about doing something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) 
{
    if (G481Inputs[i].Value == "") 
    {
        G481List[i] = 0;
    } 
    else
    {
        //Other code here
    }                
}
```

To assign `0` to the object in list index `i`?
The error I get is "Cannot implicitly convert type '`int`' into `....G481Vars`"

Comment: Why do you have an array of `HtmlInputText`, can't you just define your class here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set an `int` value to an object. You have objects of type `G481Vars` in your List, so you need to add instances of this type.

For example:

Instead of:

```
G481List[i] = 0;
```

do something like:

```
// All double values are 0 at default
G481List[i] = new G481Vars();

// Initialize values directly
G481List[i] = new G481Vars() { Disp = 1, IniVel = 5, ...};
```

Or if you want to remove the value form the list, you need to do this after the for-loop with following code:

```
myList.Remove(myInstance);
```